# nginx and the 405 error

Tags: nginx, http-post, http-status-code-405

I have a pelican blog with a simple contact page.

The contact page uses js to send a POST request to a PHP script which does the SMTP request to send the email. When I try this on the web browser it doesn't work and if I use curl, I get the 405 error:

```
✗ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"name":"PM","email":"p@m.com", "message":"foo"}' https://pm.com/theme/send-form.php

<html>
<head><title>405 Not Allowed</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>405 Not Allowed</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
```

My nginx location directive looks like:

```
    location / {
             # Serve a .gz version if it exists                                                                
             gzip_static on;
             # Try to serve the clean url version first                                                        
             try_files $uri.html $uri.html $uri =404;
             # allow POST on static pages                                                                      
             error_page 405 =200 $uri;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
             # If a file isn't found, 404
             try_files $uri =404;
             #Include Nginx's fastcgi configuration
             include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
             #Look for the FastCGI Process Manager
             fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
```

I took inspiration for this location directive from: https://linuxconfig.org/basic-php-7-and-nginx-configuration-on-ubuntu-16-04-linux

However, it still doesn't work and the most annoying thing is that there's no evidence of any error in any of the nginx access/error logs or php7.0-fpm error logs.

Comment: Do you have a `location` to process PHP files?

Comment: Nope, do I need one just to process PHP files? What I posted is the only location I have.

Comment: Added location, still not working, updating question.